# MathJax tex2svg doesn't render directly to SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, latex, mathjax

This will probably come across as a fast question without research, but I've been off-track for hours trying to figure it out.

I lately tried MathJax for the first time and I made a textarea that converted the text to an svg dynamically. Then I would save the svg and use it in other places. I used `tex2svg`. I remember it well. Now I tried to reuse it to render the svg to a canvas, which itself is easy, but now all I can get is a weird `<mjx-container>` element instead of paths. Documentation is much less than enough to cover this library and I can't find any way to get back a pure `<svg>` element. Please help me.

I know that you can still render the image from the `<math>` element under `<mjx-container>`>`<mjx-assistive-mml>`, but in my case, loading into an `HTMLImageElement` with `data:image/svg+xml` will put the image in a broken state, so that's a last resort.